# Solving table rounded corner CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, rounded-corners

I have this CSS rule for rounded corner:

```
th, td { padding: 8px;
         background: #E8ECE0;
         text-align: center;
         border: 1px solid #444;
         border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
thead { background-color: #446bb3  ; color :#fff; padding:4px; line-height:30px }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #F6F6EC;}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

tr:first-child td, tr:first-child th {
    border-top-left-radius: 12px; border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}
tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px; border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
table { border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin:0px; width:100%; padding:5px}
td.pd {border-bottom-left-radius: 12px; border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;}
td.pu {border-top-left-radius: 12px; border-top-right-radius: 12px;}
```

My html table is:

```
<table >
    <tbody>
      <tr >
        <td >Hello</td><td >Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
         <td >Hello</td><td >Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
         <td >Hello</td><td >Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
      <td >Hello</td><td >Hello</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

which gives me this

[image: table with rounded corner]

How do I fix this problem, as the td elements within the table and in the middle of the table have rounded corners too? I only need the first row and last row to have rounded corners.

Comment: And what's your html? And the first row and last row of the table, or first and last rows of the `thead`, `tbody`..?

Comment: Could you include some sample content for that HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your `table`'s html resembles the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First column</th>
            <th>Second column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row one, cell one</td>
            <td>Row one, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row two, cell one</td>
            <td>Row two, cell two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row three, cell one</td>
            <td>Row four, cell two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The the following CSS should work:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
/* the first 'th' within the first 'tr' of the 'thead': */
thead tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0;
}
/* the last 'th' within the first 'tr' of the 'thead': */
thead tr:first-child th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0.6em 0 0;
}
/* the first 'td' within the last 'tr' of the 'tbody': */
tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0.6em;
}
/* the last 'td' within the last 'tr' of the 'tbody': */
tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0.6em 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/).

Edited in response to question from OP:

> the border within the table is a little think, how do i make it 1px

The borders between cells are a little thick, because the left border of one cell is against the right border of the previous cells (and the same for top/bottom borders).

One way to remove that effect is to specify `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `table` element. Unfortunately the effect of this is to *also* remove/unset/override the `border-radius` declarations: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/1/).

The more complicated way is to manually remove top-borders for rows with a previous row, and the left-border of a cell that follows a cell, adding the following to the previous CSS:

```
thead + tbody tr td,
tr + tr td {
    border-top: 0;
}

tr th + th,
tr td + td {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/2/).

Edited to reduce make the CSS more durable (for single-cell rows, for the addition of a `tfoot` or the removal of the `thead`):

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
thead tr:first-child th:first-child,
tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.6em;
}
thead tr:first-child th:last-child,
tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.6em;
}

thead + tbody tr:last-child td:first-child,
tfoot tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.6em;
}
thead + tbody tr:last-child td:last-child,
tfoot tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.6em;
}

thead + tbody tr td,
tfoot + tbody tr td,
tfoot tr td,
tbody + tbody tr td,
tr + tr td {
    border-top: 0;
}

tr th + th,
tr td + td {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/4/).

There is a problem with multiple `tbody` elements, in the absence of a `tfoot` element, currently in which the first `tbody` will retain the border-radius on their lower borders.

Comment: thanks, but the border within the table is a little thick, how do i make it 1px or thinner

Comment: Yeah, I was already working on that. Also, the newest CSS should allow you to remove the `thead`, add a `tfoot` and have multiple `tbody` elements.

Comment: Unfortunately multiple `tbody` elements, without a `tfoot`, (while they'll have a uniform border-thickness) have problems with the curved lower-borders. There's no way to determine the absence of a subsequent sibling (that I can think of): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eYg78/5/).

Answer (score 6):

You can just put table into div. Styles for div (example):

```
div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden; /*notice*/
}
```

So the table corners will be hidden.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but if interior and outer borders are desired, some additional work is needed.  With a simple `td {border: 1px}` the outer border will appear thinner in the curves.  This can be addressed with `:first-child` selectors, like [David Thomas' solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16635343/519015), or by making the table slightly larger than the div and positioning it with negative `top` and `left` parameters.

Comment: simple and nice answer!!

Comment: Totally fixed my issues. I been trying many different complicated answers. Easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

This answer doesn't answer your question directly, but a variant.
If you dont want the middle columns to have rounded corners, this is a possible solution:

Illustration:

[image]

Properties for the table row (tr): update the table data (td) for the left most column:

```
tbody tr td:first-child
{
    border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0.6em;
}
```

Properties for the table row (tr): update the table data (td) for the second column:

```
tbody td:nth-child(2)
{
    border-radius: 0 0.6em 0.6em 0;
}
```

Here is an example: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rtc11/S88YL/)

If you have more than one column (td or th) you simply add something like this:

```
tbody td:nth-child(2) /* This is now the middle element out of three */
{
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
tbody td:nth-child(3) /* This is now the right most column */
{
    boder-radius: 0 0.6em 0.6em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the border radius of the td element. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to the td elements and using the id's of td elements set the border radius to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a 
`clear:both;` 
and it will be reset.
Also you can try `!important` because maybe you forget other "inline css rules" in other html codes.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old answer, I'd like to enhance it by adding my findings. In addition to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas)'s super-smart [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635182/solving-table-rounded-corner-css/16635343#16635343), I found an edge case where it doesn't exactly fit: A single-cell row! for example:

```
<table>
   <tr><th colspan="3">My header</th></tr>
   <tr><td>row1-cell1</td><td>row1-cell2</td><td>row1-cell3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row2-cell1</td><td>row2-cell2</td><td>row2-cell3</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="3">My footer</th></tr>
</table>
```

The rule for the top-right corner would overwrite the rule for the top-left corner (because it comes after it), and the rule for the bottom-right corner would overwrite the rule for the bottom left corner (for the same reason). See screen shot below:

[image: Overriden Corners]

The remedy for that is the css below (I added more selectors for various table-tr, tbody-tr, thead-tr combinations as needed, so you can also expand it to fit your markup):

```
        table td,
        table th{
            border: 1px solid #666;
        }

        table{
            width: 98%;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }

         /* alternating table row colors*/
        tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#f6f6f6; }
        tr:nth-child(odd)   { background-color:#ffffff; }

        /* set all corner radii initially to zero */
        th, td {
            border-radius: 0;
        }
        
        /*set only specific radii per corner (don't use the border-radius shorthand)*/
        thead tr:first-child th:first-child, 
        table tr:first-child td:first-child,
        tbody tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 0.6em;
        }
        thead tr:first-child th:last-child, 
        table tr:first-child td:last-child,
        tbody tr:first-child th:last-child {
            border-top-right-radius: 0.6em;
        }
        tbody tr:last-child td:first-child, 
        table tr:last-child td:first-child,
        tbody tr:last-child th:first-child {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0.6em;
        }
        tbody tr:last-child td:last-child, 
        table tr:last-child td:last-child,
        tbody tr:last-child th:last-child {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0.6em;
        }

        thead + tbody tr td,
        tr + tr td ,
        tr + tr th {
            border-top: 0;
        }

        tr th + th,
        tr td + td {
            border-left: 0;
        }

        /* shade th cells */
        table th {
            background-color: #888;
            color: #FFF;
        }
```

This results in the screenshot below, as desired:

[image: Fixed Corners]

All credit for this solution still goes to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas), especially for the adjacent cells border trick!